# Paradox or contradiction?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

If someone does not believe in ghosts, for example, why do they experience feelings of fear at the thought of such things? Is such thinking paradoxical?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/why-do-people-fear-statistically-unlikely-things

Comment: You might want to look into phobias and their causes. What your logic tells you ("That spider is totally harmless.") and what evolution or upbringing have taught you (fear conditioning) are two things.